# Font Awesome icons do not show in UWP app

Tags: font-awesome, uwp-xaml, font-awesome-5

I have recently tried adding an icon from Font Awesome 5 to a UWP project I'm working on.  After failing to get the icon I want to show in the app, I tried simplifying things by getting the icon to show in a simple test app, still with no success.  All I did to create the test app was:

- In Visual Studio, create a new Windows Universal Blank App.
- Added the Font Awesome OTF font file.

  ```
  Assets
      Fonts
          Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf
  ```
- Modified `MainPage.xaml` (following instructions provided by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts)) like so:

  ```
  <Grid>
      <FontIcon FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" FontWeight="Black" Glyph="&#xF193;" />
  </Grid>
  ```

When I run the test app, all I see where the icon should be is a square box.  According to the [icon's page](https://fontawesome.com/icons/wheelchair?style=solid), the solid version I'm trying to use is in the free version of the font and I have correctly set the font weight to match the configuration of the font family.

Other things I've tried:

- Different paths for the Font Family:

  - `Font Awesome 5 Free Solid`
  - `/Assets/Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid`
  - `ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid`
- Different minimum version on the UWP project configuration.
- Different version of Visual Studio.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 for my (real) app because it has certain legacy requirements.  Couldn't get this font thing to work in Visual Studio 2019 either.
- Different font character.  I tried the alternate accessibility symbol provided by Font Awesome which, according to its [information page](https://fontawesome.com/icons/accessible-icon?style=brands), is in the `Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf` font file.  And yes, for this case I did reset the font weight to `Normal` (400).
- A different control.  Tried using a `TextBlock` instead of `FontIcon` with same settings (Font Family, Font Weight, Text instead of Glyph, etc.)

*Nothing* has worked; I have never seen any of the Font Awesome icons I've tried to use appear in my app, every time showing the square box.  Is there anything else I haven't tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be using the wrong font name.

`Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf` Its real font name is not `Font Awesome 5 Free Solid`, but `Font Awesome 5 Free`, please use the following code：

```xml
FontFamily="/Assets/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free"
```

In addition, please make sure your font file's `Build Action` (right-click the file, choose `Properties`) is **Content**, it can guarantee that your font file will be added into the package correctly.

Best regards.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it!  What appears to have thrown me off here is that in the XAML designer, when I select the font family from the drop-down list (in the Text section of the Properties tool window) it sets the Font Family attribute to "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid".  Also, if I open the font OTF file (from Explorer) in the font previewer app, it clearly states at the top "Font name: Font Awesome 5 Free Solid".  Do fonts have multiple names or something?

Comment: Another gotcha I ran into before I got this working in my real app: my UI layer is in a separate class library project, which is also where I put all my visual resources including the fonts.  I had to move the fonts into the main application (entry point) project before they appeared in the UI.  Images I already had in my UI class library still load fine from there though.  Weird.

Comment: This is indeed a misleading issue. When the font is displayed to people, it will show an easy-to-read name, which may not be the original name of the font. Although the display name of most fonts is the same as the original name, `FontAwesome` uses different names, which may be a choice to distinguish different font types. For your last question, the reason is that when the application is build, your resources will be packaged in the same directory.